# Query to get comparative result from two column

Tags: mysql

I want multiple columns list with status 404 and Agent bot using the SQL query. Is this possible in the SQL query? is there any SQL function for that?

```
Status -    Agent 
404    -    bot
200    -    Android
400    -    bot
400    -    Android
200    -    bot
200    -    bot
200    -    bot
```

Result what I'm expecting:

```
404  -  bot
404  -  bot
```

Comment: your question is somehow complicated so prove it with full information

Comment: Explain how ONE source row (404, 'bot') resulted in TWO output rows with this value pair.